# New page for each Image?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm currently working on a website that will have lots of pictures, using mostly only javascript and HTML. My website is going to have lots of images displayed on the home page, and when one is clicked on it will take the user to a page where it shows the image they clicked on, along with a share to Facebook button, a comments section, and a description.

The problem is my site is going to have a lot of image, and it would take forever to create a separate html file for every single one of those images. I do realize I could easily do this with javascript, however i really need each image to have a different url so that the share to Facebook button will work.

I looked at some other picture websites, and 9gag had exactly what i wanted on my site, each image had a number assigned to it in the url, whenever i clicked the next button all it did was change the number at the end of the url, except with 9gag the images are uploaded by users, so the site must somehow create another url each time someone uploads a new image, and I'm looking for a way to do this except I'm the one choosing all of the images.

Comment: just write, what you have tried and what is your problem, rather than writing the whole story.

Comment: You are not supposed to manually create HTML documents for each photo. This is why there are **Web Applications**, **Web Platforms** and web programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

Generally , the number in the URL is the the ID of the post stored in the database. These numbers are automatically assigned (assuming your ID is auto increment)

Answer (score 0):

Index your picture's names into an array then post the variable in the url so that the page will display that image.  Like showimage.html?image_path=picture1